# Have a CSV file with Business Names, Need to Perform Web Search on All

Tags: python, google-search-api

I have a list of roughly 550 company names that I need to perform web searches for each to determine what exactly the company does. Ideally I'd like to pull the text under the first result when searching Google.

I tried performing multiple searches to identify some Web API that would let me do this using Python (came up with pygoogle, but apparently that is defunct).

Does anyone know of an API that I could use? I'm thinking the pseudo-code would look something like this (not anywhere close to an expert-level coder, so I could be completely wrong)

for value in column 1 in CSV file
    do web search
    append 1st result to line

Any help would be very appreciated, especially if you know of a product or service that already exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Locu is a great API that provides real time business data. You could iterate through each name in the csv using next()(I like python) and do a call to Locu's API using the business name.

https://dev.locu.com/

Comment: Thanks Ashley! I will be looking into this.